# Is there a way to adjust Excel csv cells from a yyyy format to a dd.mm.yyy format?

Tags: python

I have a Excel csv file with different columns with the German format `dd.mm.yyy`. I would like to transfer them to the Format yyyy and write those adjusted columns in a new file.

My problem is the handling of cells with the format yyyy.

```
anfang = str('01.01')

with open("../data/Lauritz1.csv", "r") as file:
    for line in file:            
        data = line.strip().split(";")
        for i in data:
            if len(i) == 4:
                data = data.insert(0,anfang)
                daten = data[0] + " " + str(data[3][6:10]) + " " + str(data[6]                                                                                 [6:10]) + " " + str(data[7][6:10]) + " " + str(data[8][6:10]) + " " + str(data[10][6:10]) + " " + str(data[11][6:10])

print(daten)
```

I thought I could insert 4 additional Digits to those cells with a yyyy Format to handle them as those with the dd.mm.yyyy Format.

I get after all the

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscribable

and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

`data.insert` insert the elements but returns `None`. You should change

```
 data = data.insert(0, anfang)
```

to

```
 data.insert(0, anfang)
```